# SPFx solution adds a # in the main URL

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, modern-experience, spfx-webparts, react

I am new to SharePoint and SPFx solutions. Recently I created an SPFx solution which is basically a react spa application which replaces the homepage  of the SharePoint site. But the solution adds '#/' at the end of the main URL. Any one know why this is being added?

For example the URL I need is `https://site-name` but once the solution is deployed I see that the URL is `https://site-name#/`

Any one know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Are you facing any issue because of additional `#` in URL (you should not)? As you are using URL routing, your default router must be `#`. So, whenever, you load the SPA, it adds the the default routers (#) at the end of the site page URL.

Comment: I dont face any issue but a bit odd to see the # at the end of the url

Comment: check link given in my answer & see if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You are using URL routing (react routing) in your SPFx solutions and your default router must be #.

So, whenever you load the SPA, it adds the the default router (#) at the end of the site page URL.

However, you should not face any issues because of this additional `#` in the URL.

Check this thread if it helps you to remove `#` from the URL: [How to stop /#/ in browser with react-router?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25086832/how-to-stop-in-browser-with-react-router)

Comment: yes I don't face any issue with the #. Its just a bit strange and not consistent with the other sharepoint page urls

Comment: I agree with your point but it is just because you are using custom web part with react routing.